# Ubuntu 13.04 Unity Social Lens Not Showing Anything

Tags: unity, lenses

My Unity social lens is empty. I've enabled social networking in my online accounts. I've installed the Friends Twitter client, which is working fine. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Is this the final release?

Comment: Have you enabled 'include online search results when searching in the dash' from the privacy menu in settings?

Comment: No, that was off. I've switched it back on and the lens is showing Twitter now. Cheers!